# My image keeps disappearing when I add Opengl transformations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

My image disappears if I add Opengl transformations.

```
    void renderFileButton()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 320, 0, 240, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(file_vertices), file_vertices,
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(fileButtonVertexData), (GLvoid *) 
        offsetof(fileButtonVertexData, fileButtonPositionCoordinates));

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(fileButtonVertexData), (GLvoid *) 
        offsetof(fileButtonVertexData, fileButtonTextureCoordinates));

    loadsprite("files/sprites/options.png");

    glScalef(0, 0, 1);
    glRotatef(180, 1, 0, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

    glPopMatrix();

}
```

Could someone tell me where I'm in the wrong here?

Comment: Show the code with no transformations that does display something.

Answer (score 2):

You've scaled by zero.  That makes the object's size zero.  No surprise that it disappears.

In the future, you can troubleshoot by adding one transformation at a time, and trying to add a transformation that doesn't do anything (scale by 1, rotate by 0, translate by 0).  Then increase the transformation slowly until you get to your intended value.

Also, your `glPopMatrix` is undoing all your transformations.

Finally, I don't see any actual rendering.  Just a lot of state manipulation.

Comment: I have a separate rendering function for all sprites that go onto the screen. This function just groups it all so it can go on screen. @BenVoigt

Comment: @PoppieSolumon: Well, all your transformations are being undone by `glPopMatrix`.

Comment: I also did the steps you told me to but as soon as I add glRotatef and glTranslate to the party it again disappears.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem after playing with it all last night. The transformation order was the issue.

```
glTranslatef(100, 100, 0);
glRotatef(180.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
glScalef(-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
```

This does the job, that is all.

Comment: Looks to me like the scaling *values* were an issue, like I said in my answer.  I'm also sure that you changed more of the code than this, because in the code you showed, `glPopMatrix` kills any transformation you make.

Comment: Yes and I thank you for pushing me in the right direction. @BenVoigt